# Как сохранить кавычки в csv pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Есть CSV

```
aaa,   ddd,    eee,   last_col
a,    "d f",   "b,c", last
```

Cкрипт должен сделать из него:

```
aaa,   ddd,    eee,   last_col, 0, 1
a,    "d f",   "b,c", last,     b, c
```

Но в колонки ddd убираются кавычки и получаю файл типа:

```
aaa,   ddd,    eee,   last_col, 0, 1
a,     d f,   "b,c",  last,     b, c
```

Из-за этого кое-где уезжает колонка last_col.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить.

```
..., quoting = csv.QUTE_ALL #не подходит
```

Собственно скрипт:

```py
import pandas as pd
file = 'users.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', encoding='utf-8')
res = df["eee"].str.split(",", n=1, expand=True)

for x in res:
    df[x] = res[x]

df.to_csv('ok.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: что значит `"уезжает колонка last_col"` и почему не подходит `csv.QUTE_ALL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для pandas в вашем примере пробел не является разделителем, и столбец ddd содержит текст `d f`

Уезжать у вас может в другой программе просмотра (например, в excel), если указаны разделители и пробел и запятая.